# How to merge multiple cox regression models in forest_model?

Tags: r

I would like to create a single forest plot out of several cox regression models using the forest_model package. I want to look at variable "Income" in a minimal adjusted model (coxami_min_adjust) as well as a fully adjusted model (coxami_fully_adjust) in the same plot. The package comes with "model_list" and "merge_models" but all my tries ends in error. If possible I would also like separate colours for each of the models. Thanks!

```
 forest_model(
  coxami_min_adjust,
  covariates = c("Income"),
  exponentiate = NULL,
  funcs = NULL,
  factor_separate_line = FALSE,
  format_options = forest_model_format_options(colour = "black", text_size=4.5),
  theme = theme_forest(),
  limits = NULL,
  breaks = NULL,
  return_data = FALSE,
  recalculate_width = TRUE,
  recalculate_height = TRUE,
  model_list = NULL,
  merge_models = TRUE,
  exclude_infinite_cis = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We just need to pass models as a named list

```
library(survival) 
library(forestmodel)

model_adj = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age, data=lung) 
model_unadj = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data=lung)

#1 and 2 to ensure order 
forest_model(model_list = list("1. Cox Unadj" = model_unadj, "2. Cox Adj" = model_adj))
```

[image]